# case-sensitive * with ignorecase on

Tags: search

I like the behavior of the `'smartcase'` option, which lets searches I type in by hand be case-insensitive by default, case-sensitive when there are any capital letters. I also like the behavior of the `'noignorecase'` option, which lets searches generated by the editor (as when hitting `*` or `#`) be case-sensitive by default.

Unfortunately, `'smartcase'` only does its magic when `'ignorecase'` is on, so now I have a conflict: I can either get the nice behavior for hand-generated searches or the nice behavior for machine-generated searches, but not both.

How I can I get both nice behaviors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can fix that for the `*` command by putting the following mapping in your `~/.vimrc`.

```
nnoremap * <silent> *N:let @/.='\C'<CR>n
```

When you type `*`, the mapping first executes the normal `*` command, then jumps back to the original word (`N`), then appends `\C` to the search expression (`:let @/.='\C'<CR>`), which makes it case-sensitive, and finally jumps forward again (`n`).

A complete compendium of bindings which doesn't clobber jumps (using Vitor's trick from the comments) and supports both forward and backwards search looks like this:

```
nnoremap <silent>  * :let @/='\C\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>'<CR>:let v:searchforward=1<CR>n
nnoremap <silent>  # :let @/='\C\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>'<CR>:let v:searchforward=0<CR>n
nnoremap <silent> g* :let @/='\C'   . expand('<cword>')       <CR>:let v:searchforward=1<CR>n
nnoremap <silent> g# :let @/='\C'   . expand('<cword>')       <CR>:let v:searchforward=0<CR>n
```

Comment: KISS: `:nnoremap <silent> * :let @/='\C\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>'<CR>n` (the last S stands for "solution";)

Comment: @Vitor I like the idea of your solution because it doesn't clobber the jump registers, but it doesn't seem to work: after executing that `nnoremap`, the `*` key doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Vitor Oops, I put the `<silent>` in the wrong place -- as did garyjohn! Your code works well, thanks.

Comment: How could this solution be implemented in Lua / Neovim.

Comment: @71GA I migrated this to my `init.vim` when I switched, and it has continued to work just fine.

Comment: @DanielWagner Huh, this did not work for me. This is why I am asking about the Lua way. :) Maybe I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of garyjohn/Vitor's solution that is a closer match to `*`'s behaviour in a few ways.

Making it an `expr` map fixes two things:

- 'hlsearch' -- turns on highlight immediately instead of after next `n`
- counts -- `3*` skips the first two results

And explicitly handle some others:

- `#` when in the middle of a word -- jump to previous match instead of start of current match
- empty strings -- error
- nonwords -- `*` on `)` at end of line doesn't do wholeword

```
function! s:SearchCword(wholeword, direction) abort
    let query = expand('<cword>')
    if empty(query)
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echomsg "E348: No string under cursor"
        echohl None
        return ""
    endif
    " Doing * on a nonword character at end of line produces no word
    " characters so wholeword is invalid.
    if a:wholeword && query =~# '\w'
        let query = '\<'.. query ..'\>'
    endif
    let @/ = query ..'\C'
    let searchforward = a:direction ==# 'n'
    let suffix = ''
    if !searchforward
        " v:searchforward is reset after functions so it must be part of our
        " returned command instead.
        let suffix = ":let v:searchforward=0\<CR>"
    endif
    if searchforward || s:IsCursorAtStartOfWord(expand("<cword>"))
        return a:direction .. suffix
    endif
    return a:direction..a:direction .. suffix
endfunction
function! s:IsCursorAtStartOfWord(query) abort
    let index_in_word = match(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') ..'c'.. a:query)
    return index_in_word > 0
endfunction
nnoremap <expr>  * <SID>SearchCword(1, "n")
nnoremap <expr>  # <SID>SearchCword(1, "N")
nnoremap <expr> g* <SID>SearchCword(0, "n")
nnoremap <expr> g# <SID>SearchCword(0, "N")
```

I've added SearchCword to [vim-searchsavvy](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-searchsavvy) as `searchsavvy#SearchCword()`. It supports a few more options (like making `*` follow 'smartcase' rules instead of always case sensitive).

Comment: Cool. I wonder if the echoerr can be replaced by throw? Although honestly I’m pretty sure I have both smartcase and ignorecase set and don’t have this issue with `*`, but I could be misremembering.

Comment: throw causes "Error detected while processing..." but we want an error message like the default behaviour. (You got my hopes up for a version of echoerr that's good for producing pretty error messages. : )

Comment: With `set smartcase`, `*` on "FizzBuzz" will match "Fizzbuzz". The smart logic only applies to user typed searches. The help suggests doing `/<Up>`