# Disable case sensitive auto-completion, while "smartcase" search is enabled?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, search, autocompletion, letter-case

I like the behavior of `smartcase` while searching, and I like Vim's auto-completion options, but I don't like them together. Is there any way to keep `smartcase` enabled, but have auto-completion results (`<C-n>`, `<C-p>`, and all `<C-x>` prefixed keys) always be completely case sensitive? Maybe some clever remap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update:

I created a plugin named [vim-idetools](https://github.com/lukelbd/vim-idetools) that implements this feature along with a bunch of related refactoring tools. Feel free to try it out.

---

Original answer:

Well, I figured out a way to do this. Just put this in your `.vimrc`

```
set smartcase
au InsertEnter * set noignorecase
au InsertLeave * set ignorecase
```

Now, when the popup menu opens up, `noignorecase` will be turned on and only case-sensitive completions will be listed. Don't know why I hadn't thought of this! Note smartcase only works when `ignorecase` turned on by overriding case-insensitivity whenever a capital letter is included in the search string.

On a somewhat related note, I also have in my `.vimrc` the lines

```
nnoremap <silent>  * :let @/='\C\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>'<CR>:let v:searchforward=1<CR>n
nnoremap <silent>  # :let @/='\C\<' . expand('<cword>') . '\>'<CR>:let v:searchforward=0<CR>n
nnoremap <silent> g* :let @/='\C'   . expand('<cword>')       <CR>:let v:searchforward=1<CR>n
nnoremap <silent> g# :let @/='\C'   . expand('<cword>')       <CR>:let v:searchforward=0<CR>n
```

which make "*" or "#" searches for the word under the cursor *case-sensitive*, whether or not ignorecase is on. This was from [this vi stackexchange thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/case-sensitive-with-ignorecase-on).

The reasoning behind this setup is that I often use `/` and `?` searches to quickly navigate through a file (easier to do if they are case insensitive), while I use `*` and `#` to perform word or WORD replacements with `ciw` and the popup menu to complete case-sensitive variable names.