# Force `gd` to be case-sensitive with ignorecase on

Tags: search

I have the following options:

```
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch
set wrapscan
```

The first two options cause the searches to be case-insensitive if there is no uppercase letter in the pattern.

I want this option to be disabled for the `gd` functionality, and preferably its variants.

I wanted the same for `:h star`, too, and got it from a [vi.SE answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/34553/16280). Sadly, this concept cannot be used to implement `gd`, because `gd` analyzes a few choices to guess where the declaration of the variable under cursor might be (details in `:h gd`). One needs to implement that with the query appended with `\C` to make the search case-sensitive.

Emulating the default implementation of `gd` is the real work here.

Comment: Can't you simply unset `ignorecase` and `smartcase` before doing `gd` and then reset them to their previous value?

Comment: @romainl If you mean switching them manually or with a keybinding, then yes. But if you mean in a function, then I don't think so, because when I switch `noic` back to `ic`, the matches/highlights will re-sync.

Comment: @romainl, you're right. I just missed/overlooked a step. Working fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing romainl's comment, we execute the following sequence:

- enable case-sensitive search
- execute normal `gd` key
- enable case-insensitive search

I tried that before posting a question here. It has the limitation that after `:set noignorecase`, it'll highlight the case-insensitive matches.

I figured out later that we can circumvent this problem by setting the current search register itself to forcefully match in a case-sensitive manner, with `:h /\C`.

```
nnoremap <silent> gd
      \ :let _is_ic = &ic<CR>
      \:set noic<CR>
      \:normal! gd<CR>
      \:let @/ = @/ .. '\C'<CR>
      \:let &ic = _is_ic<CR>
      \:unlet _is_ic<CR>
```